# Scripting out Oracle objects

Tags: database, oracle, scripting

I have recently been given an existing oracle database that i want to script out the various objects and its static data so that i can place the objects under source code control and when necessary rebuild the database from scratch.

Does any one have any scripts or tools that i could look at to assist me.

Comment: Just back up the database like normal people.

Comment: Khb, i think you're missing the point here. I don't intend to use these scripts as a backup method we'll do that for the production db. What i want to do is set base point, from which any new development is made. We can then better identify what changes are made, when and by whom.

Comment: I was missing the point and apologize, you could try having a look at the user_source/all_source tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd look at something like:
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, owner) from dba_objects.
Stick it in a PL/SQL procedure to write each object's DDL to its own file with UTL_FILE.

Answer (score 1):

For tools I'd recommend Oracle's [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html), it has both an automatic scripting for objects and has support for some source control utilities (CVS and Subversion specifically).

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use either EXPORT/IMPORT (if any version up to and including 11g) or DATA PUMP (if 11g and maybe 10G)

At command line on the server enter 'exp help=Y' and you should get enough detail on parameters.  Decide if you want the whole DB or one schema, data or not, etc.